# Implement Plus 1 or Thumbs Up system for iPhone app

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c

My app is a question/answer type forum for the iphone, where users view questions and answer. I'd like to implement a thumbs up system so users can give good answers the "thumbs" up. My backend is all php, so essentially when a user posts a question or answer, the data is passed via URL to my php script, which then inputs the data to my database.

Each user, when they post, will have their Rating shown, such as "Rating: 24".

What's the best way to implement such a system?

Thanks to everyone in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This tutorial covers in-depth of what you want:

- [Voting system with jQuery, Ajax and PHP](http://www.9lessons.info/2009/08/vote-with-jquery-ajax-and-php.html). A very detailed tutorial on Dzone like voting system with jQuery, Ajax and PHP. This script helps you to display user votes on blog post.
  [image]

Comment: Thanks shamittomar, this helps me with my backend php coding, but any help with the iphone portion? Will it just be a button that increases the field by 1 in my database? Sounds like it could be simple, however, I want to make sure that someone can't hit the vote button 30 times for one answer.

Comment: See this: http://github.com/zueos/ZIStoreButton. It's a "BUY NOW" button like in the App store but if you edit it you should be able to make it say anything you like and it will only be able to be pressed once.

Comment: Thanks Joshua, i'll mess around with that.